# How can I save image name and coordinates into save.txt file

Tags: java, arrays, filewriter

Can you tell me what is wrong with my `filewriter`? I want the name of the image and the image coordinates saved into the file `save.txt`. Is there something I am missing? Am I even on the right track? This is my second project. My first was to make an array that can store images.

```
else if (savePicture.isPointInElement(clickX, clickY)){ //start of save code
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter ("save.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayhat.numElements; i++){
            if (arrayhat.images[i].isShowing){
                fw.write("hat" + arrayhat.images[i].getXCenter() + " " + arrayhat.images[i].getYCenter() + " ");
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayblunt.numElements; i++){
            if (arrayblunt.images[i].isShowing){
                fw.write("blunt" + arrayblunt.images[i].getXCenter() + " " + arrayblunt.images[i].getYCenter() + " ");
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arraydealwithit.numElements; i++){
            if (arraydealwithit.images[i].isShowing){
                fw.write("dealwithit" + arraydealwithit.images[i].getXCenter() + " " + arraydealwithit.images[i].getYCenter() + " ");
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayweed.numElements; i++){
            if (arrayweed.images[i].isShowing){
                fw.write("weed" + arrayweed.images[i].getXCenter() + " " + arrayweed.images[i].getYCenter() + " ");
            }
        }
        fw.close();
        System.out.println("saved");
    }
    else if (loadPicture.isPointInElement(clickX,  clickY)){//start of load code
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (new File("save.txt"));
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayhat.numElements; i++){
            arrayhat.removeimage(arrayhat.images[i], grouphat);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayhat.numElements; i++){
            arrayblunt.removeimage(arrayblunt.images[i], groupblunt);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayhat.numElements; i++){
            arraydealwithit.removeimage(arraydealwithit.images[i], groupdealwithit);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayhat.numElements; i++){
            arrayweed.removeimage(arrayweed.images[i], groupweed);
        }
        while (sc.hasNext()){
            String word = sc.next();
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            switch(word){
                case "hat":
                    arrayhat.addImage(x, y, grouphat);
                    break;
                case "blunt":
                    arrayblunt.addImage(x, y, groupblunt);
                    break;
                case "dealwithit":
                    arraydealwithit.addImage(x, y, groupdealwithit);
                    break;
                case "weed":
                    arrayweed.addImage(x, y, groupweed);
                    break;
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
```

And this is my sticker class

```
public class sticker {

    public EZImage[] images;
    public int numElements = 0;
    public String filename;

    void arraysticker(EZImage image, String name, int x, int y){
        image = EZ.addImage(name, x, y);
    }
    public void addImage(int X, int Y, EZGroup group) {
        images[numElements] = EZ.addImage(filename, X, Y);
        group.addElement(images[numElements]);
        numElements++;
    }
    public sticker (int size, String file){
        filename = file;
        images = new EZImage[size];
    }
    public void removeimage(EZImage image, EZGroup group){
        if (containsElement(image)){
            group.removeElement(image);
            EZ.removeEZElement(image);
            image = null;
        }
    }
    public boolean containsElement(EZImage element){
        for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
            if (element == images[i]){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Describe your question more clear, choose a title that reflect your exact problem

Comment: please show us the if conditional that your initial "else" block is paired with, as this code may be skipped entirely:  resulting in no file being written.

Answer (score 1):

You're using regular java arrays.

They need to extend the Party class

In all seriousness, this block of code is beginning with an "else" keyword and might be skipped based on the prior logic:  please show us the if condition your  initial "else" block is paired with.